# Wordpress uri routing

Tags: php, wordpress, uri

I am trying to display details of a specific article in my wordpress where the uri displaying **title** and **id** , for example like `http://www.example.com/article/title/id`. I have created a page called `Article` as a parent and make another page called `Details` for viewing a specific article and when preview the page the url will show `http://www.example.com/article/details`.

In the `Article` page, I am displaying all article that I fetch from database using hard code php. So when a user click one of the article, user will be redirected to the details of the article which I wanted to display at `Details` page. Means that, article ID will be passed through the **uri** and only select from database and display.

Now I am stuck at displaying the **title** and **id** at `uri` and getting the **id** value from `uri` to make a database filtering.

Answer (score -1):

I hope i'll understand your question in the right way. You should think about "permalinks". First you should check the settings of your wordpress, which option you selected. Also a powerfull tool to use is your htaccess file on your server.

Comment: Permalink settings won't help here, also you should include some more information about solving this using the htaccess file.